# How to fill the array of sets by key and sum the values Lodash.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am using **JS** and **LoDash** library.

Data that I receive from the server looks like this :

```
const statsToSort = [
{name: "critA", value: 11111},
{name: "critA", value: 11},
{name: "critA", value: 221},
{name: "critA", value: 54},
{name: "critB", value: 1222},
{name: "critC", value: 231},
{name: "critD", value: 323},
{name: "critC", value: 0},
]
```

I Need to **rearrange it, summ the values for the same keys and reOrganise it.** For this I created the following array:

```
let finalStats = [{ "critA": 0 }, { "critB": 0 }, { "critC": 0 }, { "CritD": 0 }];
```

I am trying to use the Lodash library to *fill* the finalStats jumping of the name and summing the values.

The function I have so far is like this:

```
function mergeNames(arr) {
    return _.chain(arr).groupBy('name').mapValues(function (v) {
        return _.sum(v);
    })
```

The expected result is supposed to be like this:

```
/**
statsToSort:[
{name: "critA", value:11397},
{name: "critB", value:1222},
{name: "critC", value:231},
{name: "critD", value:323}, 
*/
```

So far my function that I have shown does ...Nothing. Like, at all. It does not even sort the array by keys.

Question:
Can you help me

- modify the function to get the result I mentioned
- maybe add another layer to the function so that it would do the populating of the finalStats array considering that the names might not be alphabetically arranged and statsToSort might not contain one or few names that are to be populated in the finalStats.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please state what you have and what you like to get. it is quite unclear to me ...

Comment: @NinaScholz I have modified a question a bit. is it any clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do what you're after:

```js
const statsToSort = [
    {name: "critA", value: 11111},
    {name: "critA", value: 11},
    {name: "critA", value: 221},
    {name: "critA", value: 54},
    {name: "critB", value: 1222},
    {name: "critC", value: 231},
    {name: "critD", value: 323},
    {name: "critC", value: 0},
]

let mergeNames = arr => _(arr)
    .groupBy('name')
    .mapValues(vals => ({
        name: vals[0].name,
        value: _.sumBy(vals, 'value')
    }))
    .value()

let finalStats = mergeNames(statsToSort)
console.log(finalStats)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i was looking for!. I guess I will find a way to cross -fill the final map by myself but this step is already a big deal for me. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a map and get the summed values.

```js
const
    statsToSort = [{ name: "critA", value: 11111 }, { name: "critA", value: 11 }, { name: "critA", value: 221 }, { name: "critA", value: 54 }, { name: "critB", value: 1222 }, { name: "critC", value: 231 }, { name: "critD", value: 323 }, { name: "critC", value: 0 }],
    result = Array
        .from(
            statsToSort.reduce((m, { name, value }) => m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + value), new Map),
            ([name, value]) => ({ name, value })
        )
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the OP is already using lodash, there's no need to replicate its functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! this indeed does what was requested but as a specification I was looking for a the underscore library solution in particular ( i mentioned it). I will definitely keep your solution on a side for some other projects! Cheers!